# Is it possible to set a button unclickable without having it turning into color gray ?

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I have a program that contains records, and when it opens, I want all the the textfields, the comboboxes and the picture uneditable ,the person's picture is set on a button , when i set that button to btnPicture.setEnabled(false) , the button's icon containing the picture turns blurry. Also if I set the comboboxes to cmbCombobox.setEnabled(false)  the text turns grey, and it is hard to read, is it also possible to set it uneditable without turning it into grey ?

[image]

Comment: I just *have* to ask... Is this screenshot your actual application?

Comment: As for the button: You could just ignore the click in the listener if some disabled-flag is set. It would still seem clickable though so this might not be a good solution regarding usability. The user would expect something to happen if he clicks the button.

Comment: The suggestion from @AndréStannek is probably best/easiest. Another option would be to look into setting the disabled colours for the button to be the same as the enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion sir @AndreStannek you did gave me an idea